# Why is the output of top command not the same as /proc?

Tags: linux, proc, top

Sometimes I see the output of `top` output like this[image: top]

But when I try to access `/proc`, it gives me different information, like this[image]

Why do I see different session ID from `top` and `/proc`?

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/